# How to set SSRS print page to Portrait Orientation for size 8.5"x 7.0"?

Tags: reporting-services, power-bi-report-server

I want to setup a SSRS page properties to size 8.5" x 7.0" and Orientation Portrait for bank checks printing.

When selecting Orientation: Portrait, Paper size: Custom, Width: 8.5", Height: 7" and clicking OK button on page properties, system automatically changes the orientation to Landscape.

Do we have a way to change the default property?

Answer (score 0):

Landscape means that the width is greater than the height.  It doesn't mean that the entered dimensions are always flipped.  If you look in the RDL file, there's no record of whether you chose Landscape or Portriat.  It just stores the page width and height:

```
    <PageHeight>7in</PageHeight>
    <PageWidth>8in</PageWidth>
    <LeftMargin>1in</LeftMargin>
    <RightMargin>1in</RightMargin>
    <TopMargin>1in</TopMargin>
    <BottomMargin>1in</BottomMargin>
    <Style />
  </Page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Press F4 on Design screen, you will see properties bar. There is a button (looks like a wierd spaceship or key) named "property pages".Paper size, orientation, mergins etc. can be set here